# How to select multiple time series in a Prometheus line graph

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics

the problem I'm having is the following: I send some memory values to my Prometheus instance, each including the host of the generating metric. Something like the following example:

```
Java_HeapMemoryUsage_max{host="host_1"} 4108320768 1710496990682
Java_HeapMemoryUsage_max{host="host_2"} 446218158 1710496990682
Java_HeapMemoryUsage_used{host="host_1"} 116086264 1710496990682
Java_HeapMemoryUsage_used{host="host_2"} 8786264 1710496990682
```

With these, I need to create a graph like the following one, displaying the data previously sent:
[image]

What I want to do is to be able to select **all the metrics for a given host**:this means that, for example, I click on the "Used host_1" metric label, also the "Max host_1" label will be selected. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this in vanilla version of Grafana. Maybe something like this might be implemented through plugins, but I would argue that this is incorrect way of approaching situation.

You can create a variable `host` and use it in your query to limit shown metrics.
For example, if your current query looks like `Java_HeapMemoryUsage_max` you can modify it to `Java_HeapMemoryUsage_max{host="$host"}`.

And if you want to still be able to see all or multiple hosts on your graphs - you can add options *Include All option* (with custom value `.+`) or *Multi-value* respectively, and replacing `=` with `=~` in your selector (as in `Java_HeapMemoryUsage_max{host=~"$host"}`)